# Does iPad 3 supports wireless charging?

Tags: ipad, wifi, charger

I am wondering if iPad 3 or any iPad version supports wireless charging?

Can I use samsung's w'less  charger for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not natively no. There are no current Apple devices supporting wireless charging out of the box.

There are however adapters for some devices, mostly phones rather than tablets. Not sure how useful a wireless charging adapter would be for an iPad.